# How to add multiple columns to a data.frame in one go?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have following dataframe and vector:

```
ddf = data.frame(a=rep(1,10), b=rep(2,10))
xx = c("c", "d", "e", "f")
```

How can I add to the dataframe new empty columns which are named with items in xx ?

I tried following but it does not work:

```
ddf = cbind(ddf, data.frame(xx))
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 10, 4
```

Following also does not work:

```
for(i in 1:length(xx)){
    ddf$(xx[i]) = ""  
}

Error: unexpected '(' in:
"for(i in 1:length(xx)){
ddf$("
 }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This will get you there:

```
ddf[xx] <- NA

#   a b  c  d  e  f
#1  1 2 NA NA NA NA
#2  1 2 NA NA NA NA
#3  1 2 NA NA NA NA
#...
```

You can't directly use something like `ddf$xx` because this will try to assign to a column called `xx` rather than interpreting `xx`. You need to use `[` and `[<-` functions, using the square brackets when you are dealing with a character string/vector - like `ddf["columnname"]` or `ddf[c("col1","col2")]`, or a stored vector like your `ddf[xx]`.

The reason why it selects columns is because `data.frames` are lists essentially:

```
is.list(ddf)
#[1] TRUE

as.list(ddf)
#$a
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
# 
#$b
# [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

...with each column corresponding to a list entry. So if you don't use a comma to specify a row, like `ddf["name",]` or a column like `ddf[,"name"]`, you get the column by default.

---

In the case that you are working with a 0-row dataset, you can not use a value like `NA` as the replacement. Instead, replace with `list(character(0))` where `character(0)` can be substituted for `numeric(0)`, `integer(0)`, `logical(0)` etc, depending on the class you want for your new columns.

```
ddf <- data.frame(a=character())
xx <- c("c", "d", "e", "f")
ddf[xx] <- list(character(0))
ddf
#[1] a c d e f
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: It doesn't work if the dataframe has zero observations, eg ddf=data.frame(a=character()), ddf[xx] <- NA, Error in value[[jvseq[[jjj]]]] : subscript out of bounds.

Comment: @Luke - interesting, though it doesn't seem right to try to add a length 1 value to a 0 row dataset. This should work: `ddf[xx] <- list(character())`

Comment: Interesting to notice that the assignment with list() also works if the dataframe does have observations. So I'd say that that is the general way, in some cases you can use the assignment with NA.

Comment: In the general way if you want to fill the new columns with NA call list(character()), if you want to fill the new columns with empty string call list(character(nrow(df))), if you want to initialize them with some value list(rep('hello',nrow(df))).

Comment: @Luke - assigning with a `list(NA)` instead of just `NA` should always be ok, since `data.frame`s are `list`s anyway. You shouldn't have to repeat the initial value `nrow(ddf)` times as R should recycle and take care of that part. I'm genuinely surprised that `list(character(0))` fills with `NA`s in a similar way though. I guess you learn something new every day.

Answer (score 9):

This seems to succeed:

```
> cbind(ddf, setNames( lapply(xx, function(x) x=NA), xx) )
   a b  c  d  e  f
1  1 2 NA NA NA NA
2  1 2 NA NA NA NA
3  1 2 NA NA NA NA
4  1 2 NA NA NA NA
5  1 2 NA NA NA NA
6  1 2 NA NA NA NA
7  1 2 NA NA NA NA
8  1 2 NA NA NA NA
9  1 2 NA NA NA NA
10 1 2 NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: Well, that is slick, now, ain't it?

Comment: @thelatemail: ddf[xx] works but how? I tried ddf$xx and ddf$(xx) but they do not work. Also why is xx in ddf[xx] taken as a column rather than rows? Please give as an answer since in comments it will be crowded. I will accept it.