# Add multiple new columns to the dataset, based on another dataset's elements

Tags: r

I have the following **products** list

```
> products
# A tibble: 311 x 1
   value                    
   <fct>                    
 1 NA                       
 2 Alternativ Economy
 3 Ambulant Balance  
 4 Ambulant Economy  
 5 Ambulant Premium  
 6 Ambulant 2               
 7 Ambulant 3               
 8 Ambulant 1               
 9 COMPLETA                 
10 HOSPITAL ECO             
# ... with 301 more rows
```

and the following df

```
> df <- data.frame(employee = c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope'), 
+           salary = c(21000, 23400, 26800), 
+           startdate = as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14')))
> df
    employee salary  startdate
1   John Doe  21000 2010-11-01
2 Peter Gynn  23400 2008-03-25
3 Jolie Hope  26800 2007-03-14
```

Now, I want to add the elements of the former (i.e. products) as variables of the latter (i.e. the df). I use

```
cbind(df, setNames(lapply(products, function(x) x = NA), products))
```

but I get an error. Can you suggest another way of doing this? What is wrong with my solution? thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you want `df[na.omit(as.character(products$value))] <- NA`.

Comment: so products should become the names of empty columns in df?

Comment: @Edo yes. So, basically I want to create 300+ columns in df

Comment: then the solution proposed by  27 ϕ 9 is what you're looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357194/how-to-add-multiple-columns-to-a-data-frame-in-one-go

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution.

```
df <- data.frame(employee = c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope'), 
                 salary = c(21000, 23400, 26800), 
                 startdate = as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14')))

products <- data.frame(value = c(NA, "Alternativ Economy", "COMPLETA"))
#products$value <- ifelse(is.na(products$value), "not_available", as.character(products$value))

cbind(df, `colnames<-`(data.frame(matrix(ncol = nrow(products), nrow = nrow(df))), products$value))

    employee salary  startdate NA Alternativ Economy COMPLETA
1   John Doe  21000 2010-11-01 NA                 NA       NA
2 Peter Gynn  23400 2008-03-25 NA                 NA       NA
3 Jolie Hope  26800 2007-03-14 NA                 NA       NA
```

I question the wisdom of having `NA`s as column names, so I'd uncomment that one line of code in there to replace `NA`s with some character string instead.