# Add empty columns where column names are from a numeric vector using tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a numeric vector, say `new_cols <- c(10, 20, 30)`, and I want to add new empty columns to an existing tibble where the column names are take from the above list. Even though the native `data.frame` doesn't support numeric columns, I can get away with it using tibble.

The answer given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357194/how-to-add-multiple-columns-to-a-data-frame-in-one-go) provides `df[new_cols]` as the solution but it wouldn't work with numeric vector.

Currently I'm looping through the vector and creating new columns using mutate, there must be a more elegant way to do this using tidyverse.

Comment: `df[new_cols] <- NA`

Comment: I've edited the question, but only after I submitted the edit did I realize that I can use `df[as.character(new_cols)]`

Answer (score 3):

The solution presented in the comment is the best. But you can also use this unusual, ugly, verbose solution:

```
library(purrr)

df %>%
  bind_cols(new_cols %>%
              map_dfc(~ df %>% 
                        transmute("{.x}" := NA)))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
      a     b x     y     z    
  <int> <int> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1     1     4 NA    NA    NA   
2     2     5 NA    NA    NA   
3     3     6 NA    NA    NA
```