# Creating multiple NEW columns using across() in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble, mutate, across

The difference between my question and existing questions is that I want to create new columns with `mutate` that do **not** depend on existing columns.

Some dummy data:

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- tibble(
    a = 1:5,
    b = LETTERS[1:5]
)
```

I know I can create new columns one-by-one like so

```
dat <- dat %>%
    mutate(foo = NA, bar = NA, bar2 = NA)
```

And I can *modify* columns more conveniently using `across`, e.g. :

```
new_vars <- c("foo", "bar", "bar2")
dat <- dat %>%
    mutate(across(all_of(new_vars), ~ replace(., is.na(.), 0)))
```

But how do I create new columns without referencing existing columns in a similar manner?  E.g. adding new columns filled with `NA`:

```
tibble(
    a = 1:5,
    b = LETTERS[1:5]
) %>% 
    # mutate(across(all_of(new_vars), ~ function(.x) NA))  # Error
    mutate(across(all_of(new_vars), NA))                   # Error
```

Open to any `tidyverse` alternatives.

Comment: I also tried replacing `new_vars` with `!!!syms(new_vars)` as I thought would be required, but this still results in an error.

Comment: To create a column requires that it have both a name and a value (or values equal to the length of the existing columns).  So you can use `setNames(rep(NA, length(new_vars)), new_vars)` to create the name value pairs, then splice this into the mutate call:  `dat %>%
  mutate(!!!setNames(rep(NA, length(new_vars)), new_vars))`.

Comment: Whoever closed this, this is not a duplicate.  The answers in the linked question use `[]` which is the code I'm trying replace - it is not pipe friendly.  I need a `tidyverse` solution.  Please reopen.

Comment: The first answer in the linked question used `[]` - the second one works too, and does not. Your question is a duplicate in the sense that the same problem has been solved but if you specifically want pipes + tidyverse, fair enough.

Comment: There are also [multiple solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214395/add-empty-columns-to-a-dataframe-with-specified-names-from-a-vector) including the one proposed by Ritchie.

Comment: @Earlien could you clarify why the `df %>% mutate(!!!setNames(rep(NA, length(new_vars)), new_vars))` approach [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74020972/12109788) and mentioned by Ritchie Sacramento does not fit you needs? It seems to work perfectly and is tidy compatible.

Comment: @jpsmith Was just looking at that - that actually does look very similar to what I was envisaging with `across`.  I'm happy to accept that as the answer (since it only got 1 vote  on that question compared to the accepted answer of 85 votes, I think a new answer is warranted.  Could you add it?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74020972/12109788) buried in the popular question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214395/add-empty-columns-to-a-dataframe-with-specified-names-from-a-vector), you can use:

```
new_vars <- c("foo", "bar", "bar2")

tibble(
  a = 1:5,
  b = LETTERS[1:5]
) %>% 
  mutate(!!!setNames(rep(NA, length(new_vars)), new_vars))
# or (thanks @joran)
# tibble::add_column(!!!setNames(rep(NA, length(new_vars)), new_vars))
```

output

```
     a b     foo   bar   bar2 
  <int> <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1     1 A     NA    NA    NA   
2     2 B     NA    NA    NA   
3     3 C     NA    NA    NA   
4     4 D     NA    NA    NA   
5     5 E     NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: This method also works with just `tibble::add_column` in place of `mutate`.

Comment: @joran thanks! I included this in the edit. I was just trying to do justice to the other answer, I also agree with your answer that base is the way to go in this context (+1!)

Answer (score 4):

I use tidyverse stuff as much as the next fellow, but the lengths we're going to to avoid doing things the simple way is getting a little silly, imho.

Here. Pipe friendly.

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- tibble(
  a = 1:5,
  b = LETTERS[1:5]
)

new_vars <- c("foo", "bar", "bar2")

# ?
# dat[new_vars] <- NA

add_vars <- function(df,vars,val){
  df[vars] <- val
  df
}

dat |>
  add_vars(df = _,vars = new_vars,val = NA)
```

You could even use an anonymous function (but only with the magrittr pipe):

```
dat %>%
  (\(x) {x[new_vars] <- NA; x})
```

This also works (with the magrittr pipe) with the `function(x)` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr::bind_cols()` and pipes:

```
library(dplyr)

tibble(a = 1:5,
       b = LETTERS[1:5]) %>% 
bind_cols(., setNames(lapply(new_vars, function(x) x = NA), new_vars))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 5
      a b     foo   bar   bar2 
  <int> <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1     1 A     NA    NA    NA   
2     2 B     NA    NA    NA   
3     3 C     NA    NA    NA   
4     4 D     NA    NA    NA   
5     5 E     NA    NA    NA
```

Although I think the **second** answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357194/how-to-add-multiple-columns-to-a-data-frame-in-one-go), on which this is based, is just as good.

If you really want `mutate`, Ritchie's answer in the comments works.

Comment: Thanks, I was just looking at that answer.  It looks so unwieldy compared to the `dat[new_vars] <- NA` approach, but at least it is tidy `compatible`.  I'm hoping there is a neater solution though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the style you're looking for:

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- tibble(
    a = 1:5,
    b = LETTERS[1:5]
)

new_vars <- c("foo", "bar", "bar2")

dat %>% 
    purrr::reduce(new_vars, ~mutate(.x, {{.y}} := 0), .init = .)
```

Instead of using `across()` we use `purrr::reduce()` which will loop over the `new_vars`.  We apply the `mutate` function to the output of the previous iteration.  We want to start with `.init = dat`, but we pipe it in.

You could even use `reduce2` if you wanted to have different values for each of the `new_vars`.