# How to Add Multiple New Columns to a Dataframe and Initialize with a Single Value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, variable-assignment

I need an elegant way to create multiple new columns and add them to an existing dataframe in R. I also want to initialize all rows for these new columns with a single value, in my case NA, so that I can overwrite them later.

Comment: Relevant previous discussion - [How to add multiple columns to a data.frame in one go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357194/how-to-add-multiple-columns-to-a-data-frame-in-one-go) , including discussion of edge-cases like adding columns to 0-row `data.frame`s.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way I found to do this is the following:

1. Create your list of new column names you want to add to your existing dataframe. 
   `newColumns <- c("Var1", "Var2")`
2. If this code is to be used for automation, you may want the functionality of determining which columns aren’t already in the dataframe so that you only add the necessary new variables to your dataset. Do this by finding the index of the variable names not currently in your dataframe. 
   `missingColumns <- which(!(newColumns %in% names(dataFrame)))`
3. Reference, write, and initialize your new variables to your dataframe. 
   `dataFrame[newColumns[missingColumns]] <- NA`

Answer (score 0):

A Tidyverse solution could use `tibble::add_column()`:

```r
library(tibble)

df <- tibble(
  x = 1:10
)

df |> add_column(y = NA, z = NA)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>        x y     z    
#>    <int> <lgl> <lgl>
#>  1     1 NA    NA   
#>  2     2 NA    NA   
#>  3     3 NA    NA   
#>  4     4 NA    NA   
#>  5     5 NA    NA   
#>  6     6 NA    NA   
#>  7     7 NA    NA   
#>  8     8 NA    NA   
#>  9     9 NA    NA   
#> 10    10 NA    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Use the `.name_repair` argument to permit column names that already exist in the dataframe.